# Increment or decrement counter on left or right arrow key press on window in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keypress

Hi I have written a block a code where the increment or decrement of a counter happens when I have selected the button element. This is the code that I have:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    };
  }


  increment = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
      })
    }
  }

  decrement = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks - 1
      })
    }
  }

  IncrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  };
  DecreaseItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks - 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem} onKeyDown={this.decrement} tabIndex="0">
          -1
        </button>
        <span>{this.state.clicks}</span>
        <button onClick={this.IncrementItem} onKeyUp={this.increment} tabIndex="0">
          +1
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I want to happen is, when I press left arrow key, it should automatically decrement the value without the requirement of the button element to be selected/focused. Similarly for the right arrow key action as well.

Can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't added the error. What is not working?

Comment: @TusharShahi There is no error, I wanted to go for a different behaviour which I am not able to figure out. Currently, to use arrow keys, I should have the browser focusing on a button. Like, when I have this button selected `<button onClick={this.IncrementItem} onKeyUp={this.increment} tabIndex="0">+1</button>`, I won't be able to decrement count. It's the same when other button is selected. I want the action of arrow key press to be independent of this requirement of focusing on the button element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case to listen for Keyboard events you have to attach event listener for document/window but not on button element.

Please refer below snippet for reference.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keydown);
  }
 componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keydown);
 }

  keydown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
      this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks + (e.keyCode === 39 ? 1 : -1)
      })
    }
  }

  IncrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  };
  DecreaseItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks - 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem} tabIndex="0">
          -1
        </button>
        <span>{this.state.clicks}</span>
        <button onClick={this.IncrementItem} tabIndex="0">
          +1
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```